# Is it good practice to use join() operator in ForkJoin pool (it smells like "blocking code")

Tags: java, concurrent.futures, fork-join

I am trying to understand if this is appropriate to use fork/join paradigm in very scalable application.
Blocking code is considered bad as it forces context switch and bad resource utilization.
Most scalable concurrent code are relies on lambda functions like RXJava/Reactor and CompleatableFuture.

But ForkJoin examples are suggesting directly using `join` operation which is usually considered blocking code. Example:

```
 static class Sum extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
      int low;
      int high;
      int[] array;

      Sum(int[] array, int low, int high) {
         this.array = array;
         this.low   = low;
         this.high  = high;
      }

      protected Long compute() {
         
         if(high - low <= 10) {
            long sum = 0;
            
            for(int i = low; i < high; ++i) 
               sum += array[i];
               return sum;
         } else {           
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            Sum left  = new Sum(array, low, mid);
            Sum right = new Sum(array, mid, high);
            left.fork();
            long rightResult = right.compute();
            long leftResult  = left.join();
            return leftResult + rightResult;
         }
      }
   }
```

I do understand that ForkJoin does not block on join but stealing other task(from same level of child-parent relationship?) - so it is not as bad as normal (no context switching, no resource waiting, mach better then JDBC connection).
But still may be there are some cases where it has some aspects of "bad" blocking cases.

The question is it good practice to use .join in such cases if application wants to be truly scalable?

Comment: Why would it be a "bad practice" to use `join` in a `Fork->Join<-Pool` solution? When you use `join` incorrectly it can lead to problems that make your program crash or make it very inefficient but it's definitely not a bad practice. It's like saying: "It's a bad practice to divide numbers because when you divide by 0, the program will crash.". However, you are correct about the problem of scalability in programs that are synchronized the usual way. Therefore there are other models like the [Actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) to design concurrent programs, which solve it.

Comment: @akuzminykh It is also interesting that in JDK code(for example Arrays.parallelSort) they avoid using join in favor of more complex mechanism `CountedCompleter` - so it is a least somehow "bad practice"

Comment: Okay, now because you've found some examples where `join` is not explicitly used, it's a "bad practice" for you? The JDK is obviously optimized as much as it probably can be. Does it mean that anything else that is not programmed the way the JDK is is code that is based on bad practices? No, it's not. It's like saying: "It's a bad practice to use Java because you can do everything far more efficient in Assembler.". Also please be aware of that `join`, again, has use cases to it that it's made for. Your examples might just not be the right ones for `join`.

Comment: I think that your definition of a "bad practice" might be just a bit off. It's definitely not a bad practice to use `ForkJoinPool` as it's intended to be used. I think the key is that you're asking about scalability and here you have a point like I've already mentioned: Normally synchronized programs can be very hard to scale. E.g. using too many `join` calls under specific circumstances will give you a stack overflow because long chains of `join` -> `fork` -> `join` -> `fork` and so on can occur. You cannot solve it without changing the algorithm so it's inherently a scalability problem.

Comment: I wrote a critique on this framework in 2010. Join() then created a  new thread to continue the execution and the join()ing thread waited.  A lot has changed since then (the CountedCompleter class for one.) I don't follow the latest code changes anymore; a waste of time. Here is the original article with links to the follow-up articles: http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html

Comment: @edharned Thank you for sharing that. It's very interesting.

Comment: @edharned Thank you for article. Would you suggest avoid using ForkJoinPool in scalable applications. And stick with normal thenApply paradigm of CompletableFuture?
Part of benefits of ForkJoin from developer standpoints is removing necessity of doing callbacks with ability to call join directly and getting results without worrying of "blocking calls". But seems like my worries are real and this is still somehow inefficient

Comment: @yura I wouldn't use join() for anything. The "fix" changes from release to release. Use CountedCompleter the way ParallelStreams does.